# GMAIL API returns different ThreadID than inboxSDK

Tags: gmail-api, inboxsdk

**Context**: I am using the *[PHP]* [Gmail API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/) and [InboxSDK](https://www.inboxsdk.com/).

When sending a message (with Gmail API), I output the message sent object ([reference here](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages#resource)).

It contains info about message ID and Thread ID.

**What is happening?**

**Id** and **ThreadID** is the same *(ok: because it is the first message in the thread)*.

But if I check the received mail with [InboxSDK](https://www.inboxsdk.com/), i see a different **ThreadID** than the one returned by GMAIL API.

**Example of what is going on**:

I send a Test email via API.

[image]

When checking the thread ID with InboxSDK though...

[image]

We can see both Thread Ids are different.

Maybe I am doing something wrong, can you please help me out with this?

**Note**: I tried this multiple times with multiple google accounts. The issue is constant.

Comment: Gmail API is not Inbox SDK

Comment: @noogui bread is not meat, still a hamburguer is made of both.

Comment: Same issue here. Have you been able to find a solution?

Comment: Ok. I did some digging and here is what I found. One time I sent a test mail and then deleted it. After that, I sent another mail with the same subject. In this case, Gmail creates a thread using that deleted email. ie,  `thread-id` of the second email is `message-id` of the first (deleted) email. But InboxSDK does not know about that deleted email (Gmail won't load this deleted mail unless you click on a link). InboxSDK will use `message-id` of second email as `thread-id` (for first mail in a thread `message-id`=`thread-id`).